# java filereader : reading a file into a char array

Tags: java, filereader

I'm having issues reading a file into a char array and then comparing each char to a random letter, let's say 'e'.

Here is my code so far, I think cbuf is null, but I don't understand, I thought this was supposed to read the contents of file into it.

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class CountCharacter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        int c;
        int countOfLetter = 0;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text.txt");
            CharBuffer cbuf = null;
            fr.read(cbuf);

            for (int i = 0; i < cbuf.length(); i++) {
                if (cbuf.charAt(i) == 'e')
                    countOfLetter++;
            }
            System.out
                    .println("The number of times 'e' occurred in this file is: "
                            + countOfLetter);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly answered your question.

`cbuf` is being initialized to null. Who is assigning to this variable, ever? Thus, where should  `fr.read(cbuf)` write the characters to?

Also, you did not give the actual problem you are experiencing!   I'd expect the `read()` line to be flagged for a NPE within the read.

And from this, your remark is exactly identifying the reason.
It is just missing to recognize that a null does not magically disapear but requires an explicit assignment.
This is what your code is missing. Initialize `cbuf`!

You then should read about the semantics of the `read()` method,
 as your code is still missing a loop to read the whole file. (Mind, the file could be larger than your buffer!)

Comment: Thanks. At first I did not understand why cbuf is null, because I thought I was making it not null by reading from my filereader into it when I wrote:

         fr.read(cbuf);

Answer (score 1):

You declared your CharBuffer cbuf as null and then attempted to use it, which is giving you a null pointer exception. Declare cbuf as follows, changing 1024 to an appropriate size for whatever file size you're using:

```
CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
```

You will also need to change the line

```
if (cbuf.charAt(i) == 'e')
```

to

```
if (cbuf.get(i) == 'e')
```